# what would be the right feature extraction methods for these images?

Tags: neural-network, feature-extraction

I am trying to classify cataract images, First i crop out the pupil area and save it in another folder, then i execute the wavelet transform on these cropped images using wavedec function and sym8 filter, then i take the approximation coefficients as the feature vector and the final step would be sending these feature vectors to neural network, after trying the neural network to classify my data set which contains 51 images,I have tried 10,20, 50, 70 hidden layers,But It shows that only 90% is the percentage of the correct classified images. so I want to increase this percentage,

So, any suggestions on what to  use  other than wavelet?
why when i increased the dataset size to 83 images the neural network showed me bad results such as 70% or 60%?!
should i stop using Neural and start looking for another classifier?

[some image from the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARWUI.jpg)

[another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lloaX.jpg)